# What are all the certificates mandatory to be provide while setting TLSVerifyClient option to demand?

Tags: openssl, pam, certificates, ldap, openldap

In my case, I had set **TLSVerifyClient** to ***demand***. I couldn't be able to establish a connection While providing **TLSCACertificateFile** alone.

While setting the **TLSVerifyClient** option ***demand*** is it mandatory to provide the following options or ***TLSCACertificateFile is enough***?

TLSCACertificateFile

TLSCertificateKeyFile

TLSCertificateFile

Regards,

Ram